# Como pegar o nome do site?

Tags: php

Imaginem um cenário em que eu possua **somente** URLs da seguinte forma, cadastradas no meu banco de dados:

```
https://www.google.com
https://www.facebook.com
https://www.youtube.com
https://www.twitter.com
```

Pensando nesse caso, e que **somente haverão URLs dessa maneira citada**, como eu poderia elaborar uma maneira de pegar o nome do site?

Por exemplo, através de regex, quando eu invocar um determinado método, e passar como valor `https://www.google.com`, ele me devolva somente a *string* Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function nome_dominio($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    $nome = explode('.',$regs['domain']);
    return ucfirst($nome[0]); // converto primeira letra para maiúscula
  }
  return false;
}

// Exemplos (todos retornam Google):
echo nome_dominio("https://mail.google.com"); // Retorna Google
echo nome_dominio("https://google.com"); // Retorna Google
```

Comment: Tem alguns problemas, por exemplo o site `http://www.saopaulo.sp.gov.br`, ele retorna `sp` ao invés de `saopaulo`, que é o nome correto. Ele trata saopaulo como subdomínio do `sp`. A solução disso é bem mais complexa, não pode ser *simples* REGEX, a não ser que liste todos os casos e coloque num REGEX.

Comment: Um outro exemplo, `http://meusite.floripa.br`, retorna `Floripa`. Ele é um TDL válido, [veja aqui](https://serverdo.in/ja-pensou-em-ter-um-dominio-floripa-br/).

Comment: @Inkeliz Eu entendo, mas esse código não é universal, serve apenas pra atender os sites no padrão da pergunta, ou seja, _site.com_ ou _site.com.br_.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo do regex em JavaScript:

```js
var urls = [
  'https://www.google.com',
  'https://www.facebook.com',
  'https://www.youtube.com',
  'https://www.twitter.com'
];

var $saida = document.getElementById("saida");

urls.forEach(function(url) {
  var nome_site = /(https\:\/\/www.)([^.]+)(.*)/g.exec(url)[2];
  nome_site = nome_site.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nome_site.slice(1)
  $saida.value = $saida.value + "\n" + url + ': ' + nome_site;
});
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="saida"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solução mais próxima para todos os casos é muito mais complexa do que um REGEX.

Infelizmente não consegui tornar isto mais amigável,o código final ficou um pouco confuso, mas creio que ainda sim dará para entender e irei explicar todo o processo.

---

### Vantagens <sub><sub><sub>(em relação a [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231294/15089))</sub></sub></sub>

- Possui maior suporte para todos os tipos de dominios, tais como `floripa.br` ou `adult.ht`.
- Possui suporte para subdominios públicos, como por exemplo `<seusite>.blogspot.com` e até `<seusite>.s3.amazonaws.com` e afins.

---

### Requisitos:

Não é preciso nenhuma extensão, plugin, framework... Somente é preciso que baixe a lista pública de todos os domínios/TLD isso está disponível aqui (https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) e que especifique o local do arquivo na linha mencionada.

Esse documento é atualizado periodicamente.

### Código:

```
function pegaNome($url)
{

    $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if (empty($url)) {
        return false;
    }

    $generico = ['com', 'org', 'net', 'edu', 'gov', 'mil'];

    $lista = array_filter(file('public_suffix_list.dat.txt'));                                             // Download: https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat
    $lista = array_merge($lista, ['*']);

    $dominio = explode('.', $url);
    $dominioTamanho = count($dominio) - 1;

    $encontrado = [];

    foreach ($lista as $tld) {

        if (!in_array(substr($tld, 0, 1), ['!', '/', "\n"], true)) {

            $correto = 0;
            $partes = explode('.', $tld);
            $partesTamanho = count($partes);

            foreach ($partes as $i => $pedaco) {

                if (!isset($dominio[$dominioTamanho - $partesTamanho + $i + 1])) {
                    break;
                }

                $pedaco = (array)trim($pedaco);
                $pedaco = $pedaco === '*' ? $generico : $pedaco;

                $correto += (int)(in_array($dominio[$dominioTamanho - $partesTamanho + $i + 1], $pedaco, true));

            }

            if ($correto === $partesTamanho) {
                $encontrado[] = $correto;
            }

        }

    }

    if ($encontrado !== 0){
        rsort($encontrado);

        foreach($encontrado as $encontro){
            if(!empty($dominio[$dominioTamanho - $encontro])){
                return $dominio[$dominioTamanho - $encontro];
            }
        }

    }

    return $url;

}
```

### Explicações:

**Arquivo:**

O arquivo possui quatro tipos de situações (ignorando espaços em branco):

```
!tld
*.tld
// tld
tld
```

O código acima ignora tanto `// tld`, que são comentários, como também `!tld`, que não sei o motivo exato.

*Caso seja `*.tld` indica que ele seria `net.tld`, `com.tld` por exemplo, na maior parte dos casos.*

**Verificações:**

Quando você pede para verificar um URL, por exemplo `https://seusite.blogspot.com` é feito exatamente o seguinte:

- Usa o `PHP_URL_HOST` para obter `seusite.blogspot.com`.
- Divide `seusite.blogspot.com` para `seusite`, `blogspot` e `com`.

Depois, precisamos verificar o é o dominio usado pelo seu website:

- Verifica se o último elemento é igual ao `ac`: `com` != `ac`
- Verifica se o último conjunto é igual ao `com.ac`, de forma que:

  - Compara o penúltimo elemento igual a `com`: `blogspot` != `com`
  - Compara o último elemento igual a `ac`: `com` != `ac`

Isso se repete por cada [linha deste arquivo](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat).

Em determinado ponto vai fazer exatamente:

- Verifica se o último conjunto é igual ao `blogspot.com`:

  - Compara o penúltimo elemento igual a `blogpost`: `blogspot` == `blogpost`
  - Compara o último elemento igual a `com`: `com` == `com`

Então irá salvar `$encontrado[] = $correto`, isso irá armazenar o valor `2`, que é o número de partes que o "subdomínio" tem (.blogspot.com = 2, .net = 1, .a.b.c = 3).

Neste mesmo domínio, nas últimas comparações vai fazer:

- Verifica se o último elemento é igual ao `.com`: `com` === `com`

Isso também irá armazenar o valor `1` ao `$encontrado`.

**Resultado**:

No final pegamos o maior número de `$encontrado` e então pegamos o nome do dominio baseado nele.

Então se `seusite.blogspot.com` tem o maior `$encontrado` como `2` então basta fazer `$dominio[count($dominio)-2-1]`.

Então porque cria uma array? Porque pode ser que informe `https://blogspot.com`, então ele iria também ser válido nos dois casos, porém o `count($dominio)-2-1` seria então `-1`. Por isso então ele passa para o proximo dominio encontrado, neste caso `.com` e irá retornar `blogspot`, normalmente.