# Como pegar o nome de domínios compostos?

Tags: php

Eu vi [Como pegar o nome do site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231279/como-pegar-o-nome-do-site) e testando vi que funciona muito bem em nomes simples, mas em nomes compostos, por exemplo:

```
https://www.stackoverflow.com
https://www.oficinacarlos.com
https://www.lucasverduras.com
```

Ele retorna tudo junto, assim:

> Stackoverflow
>
> Oficinacarlos
>
> Lucasverduras

Existiria uma maneira de receber os nomes compostos, como esses acima e devolvê-los assim:

> Stack Overflow
>
> Oficina Carlos
>
> Lucas Verduras

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
function nome_dominio($url)
{
    $pieces = parse_url($url);
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
      if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
        $nome = explode('.',$regs['domain']);
        return ucfirst($nome[0]); // converto primeira letra para maiúscula
      }
    return false;
}
```

**É necessário que a função retorne tanto nomes compostos, quanto nomes simples.**

Comment: acho difícil, pois qual seria o critério por exemplo para Stackoverflow retornar Stack Overflow? Só ai poderiamos ter muitos retornos Stac Koverflow, Stackover Flow e por ai vai. Impossivel não é, basta ter um banco de dados com todos os nomes de dominios e nomes dos sites e retornar o nome do site fazendo consulta pelo dominio. Se o universo de urls for limitado pode fazer com array Veja exemplo em https://ideone.com/HL1NkN

Comment: Acho que maneira mais fácil é simplesmente acessar a página (ex. cURL ou gets_contents) e obter a informação do `<title>` e verificar o que se aproxima com o dominio, então se o nome do site for `Stack Overflow em Portugues`, define para `Stack Overflow`. Acho que a única forma.

Comment: @Inkeliz, acho que um exemplo do que você disse como resposta, poderia trazer uma excelente resposta para essa pergunta.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis, estou fazendo isso. :D

Answer (score 2):

É dificil criar algo que funcione em todos os casos, tentei fazer o mais simples possível, mas em vários casos possui erros um tanto quanto grotesco.

### Testes:

Resultado nos TOP 30 do Alexa:

```
+----------------+-----------+
|    Dominio     |   Nome    |
+----------------+-----------+
| youtube.com    | YouTube   |
| facebook.com   | Facebook  |
| baidu.com      | Baidu     |
| wikipedia.org  | Wikipedia |
| yahoo.com      | Yahoo     |
| reddit.com     | reddit    |
| google.co.in   | Google    |
| qq.com         | Qq**      |
| amazon.com     | Amazon    |
| taobao.com     | Taobao    |
| google.co.jp   | Google    |
| twitter.com    | Twitter   |
| tmall.com      | Tmall**   |
| vk.com         | VK        |
| live.com       | Live      |
| instagram.com  | Instagram |
| sohu.com       | Sohu      |
| sina.com.cn    | Sina      |
| weibo.com      | Weibo**   |
| jd.com         | JD        |
| 360.cn         | 360       |
| google.de      | Google    |
| google.co.uk   | Google    |
| google.ru      | Google    |
| google.fr      | Google    |
| linkedin.com   | LinkedIn  |
| google.com.br  | Google    |
| list.tmall.com | Tmall**   |
| google.com.hk  | Google    |
| yandex.ru      | Yandex    |
+----------------+-----------+
```

Já entre os 199992 até 200026 do Alexa:

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|          Dominio           |                  Nome                      |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| gsm-specs.com              | GSM-specs.com - GSM-specs***               |
| cikm2017.org               | CIKM 2017                                  |
| sitkagear.com              | SITKA Gear | Turning Clothing Into Gear*** |
| laprocure.com              | La Procure                                 |
| pori.fi                    | Pori                                       |
| 1213wz.com                 | 1213wz                                     |
| unistar.by                 | Unistar                                    |
| upskirtjerk.com            | Upskirt Jerk                               |
| astarehsaghf.com           | Astarehsaghf*                              |
| dornc.com                  | Department of***                           |
| serviceacademyforums.com   | Service Academy Forums                     |
| yaledailynews.com          | Yale Daily News                            |
| rewardingexcellence.com    | rformance Ce***                            |
| lokosom.com.br             | Lokosom                                    |
| i-escape.com               | i-escape                                   |
| 90rss.com                  | 90rss                                      |
| bhdstar.vn                 | BHD STAR                                   |
| le-onze-parisien.fr        | Le Onze Parisien                           |
| criarweb.com               | CriarWeb                                   |
| fundayshop.com             | Fundayshop                                 |
| campsitephotos.com         | CampsitePhotos                             |
| spankwirefreehd.com        | Spankwirefreehd                            |
| kabudragon.com             | Kabudragon**                               |
| rebug.me                   | REBUG                                      |
| yuchaoyang.com             | Yuchaoyang*                                |
| naval.com.br               | NAVAL                                      |
| chesterfield.gov           | Chesterfield*                              |
| nururi.com                 | Nururi                                     |
| vcegdaprazdnik.ru          | Vcegdaprazdnik**                           |
| noridianmedicareportal.com | Noridianmedicareportal*                    |
| solobari.it                | Solobari                                   |
| kaddr.com                  | Kaddr                                      |
| mayoclinichealthsystem.org | Mayo Clinic Health System                  |
| sanayi.gov.tr              | Sanayi                                     |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Já entre os 390000 até 390029 do Alexa:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    catholicplanet.com     |                           Catholic Planet                           |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4jovem.com                | 4jovem                                                              |
| uploadmb.com              | UploadMB                                                            |
| 2bet.ag                   | 2Bet                                                                |
| polnakorzina.ru           | Polnakorzina**                                                      |
| kktown.com.tw             | KKTOWN                                                              |
| pension.de                | Pensionen, FerienunterkÃ¼nfte & Ferienwohnungen finden - Pension*** |
| realresultslist.com       | realresultslist*                                                    |
| hoya.co.jp                | HOYA                                                                |
| fbw.jp                    | Fbw**                                                               |
| mongol-media.com          | Mongol-Media                                                        |
| indianpediatrics.net      | Indian Pediatrics                                                   |
| dmmfree.net               | DmmFree                                                             |
| mp3gui.info               | Mp3Gui                                                              |
| xhtmlforum.de             | XHTMLforum                                                          |
| whole9life.com            | Whole9 - Let us change your life***                                 |
| swidnica.pl               | Swidnica                                                            |
| revbrew.com               | rewery | Revolution Brew***                                         |
| nasleshahvar.ir           | Nasleshahvar                                                        |
| com-private.club          | Com-private                                                         |
| crack4patch.com           | Crack 4 Patch                                                       |
| incomingsoft.de           | Incomingsoft*                                                       |
| thefrustratedengineer.com | The Frustrated Engineer                                             |
| forumdesimages.fr         | Forum des images                                                    |
| tripvillas.com            | Tripvillas                                                          |
| araxis.com                | Araxis                                                              |
| rembetiko.gr              | Rembetiko                                                           |
| krasview.ru               | Krasview                                                            |
| duckokong.com             | Duckokong*                                                          |
| hotesextubes.com          | Hot Sex Tubes                                                       |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Resultado dos links mencionados:

```
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|          Dominio           |                  Nome                   |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| stackoverflow.com          | Stack Overflow                          |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

### Principais problemas:

1. O website deve estar disponível para que funcione minimamente e acessível por cURL, sem redirecionamentos feito por javascript por exemplo, vise os casos indicados com `*`.
2. Os websites "asiáticos"/"russos" possuem maiores problemas, vise os indicados com `**`.
3. Devido ao método de funcionamento, obtendo o começo e fim pode ser que pegue um trecho muito maior do que o próprio titulo ou muito menor, vise os marcados com `***`. *Isso pode ser corrigido tentando achar string mais próxima, mas não fiz nada para corrigir isso.*

---

Como funciona?

```
function colidirTituloComNome($title, $name){

    $inicio = encontrarInicio($title, $name);
    $fim = encontrarFim($title, $name);

    if ($inicio !== false && $fim !== false){
        return mb_substr($title, $inicio, $fim - $inicio, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return ucfirst($name);
}

function encontrarInicio($title, $name){

    $achado = mb_stripos($title, $name, 0, 'UTF-8');
    if ($achado !== false){
        return $achado;
    }

    if (mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8') <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return encontrarInicio($title, mb_substr($name, 0, ceil(mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8')/2), 'UTF-8'));
}

function encontrarFim($title, $name){

    $achado = mb_strripos($title, $name, 0, 'UTF-8');
    if ($achado !== false){
        return $achado + mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8');
    }

    if (mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8') <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return encontrarFim($title, mb_substr($name, ceil(mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8')/2), null, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

Está "meio" duplicado, mas enfim é isso. A ideia é que dado uma entrada `stackoverflow` e outra `Stack Overflow em Portugues` irá tentar cortar a string até o ponto onde encontre "Stack" e também encontre "flow", assim conseguirá obter "Stack Overflow".

Existem várias outras forma de fazer isso, talvez outras bem mais precisas e eficientes, por exemplo o `similar_text` ou `levenshtein`.

Se não encontrasse ele retornaria "Stackoverflow".

---

Para obter o valor da `<title>` pode utilizar:

```
function pegaTitulo($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
            CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,                                                             // Timeout
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 2,                                                       // Timeout
            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
            CURLOPT_CAINFO => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert-2017-06-07.pem',         // Download: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert-2017-06-07.pem
        ]
    );

    if ($html = curl_exec($ch)) {

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        if ($dom->loadHTML($html)) {
            $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
            if ($list->length > 0) {
                return $list->item(0)->textContent;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

O cURL irá obter as informações da página, ele está limitado para HTTP/HTTPS e pode seguir até 2 redirecionamentos. Além disso ele irá verificar o SSL e possui um timeout para falhar caso demore muito tempo. Isso é minimamente seguro para uso público, onde o usuário poderá definir o `$url`.

Se tudo der certo, ele vai obter o conteúdo da tag `<title>` usando o `DOMDocument`.

Para pegar o nome (`https://pt.stackoverflow.com` para `stackoverflow`) pode [utilizar esta outra função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231900/15089).

Então poderá utilizar:

```
$nome = pegaNome($url);
$titulo = pegaTitulo($url);

if ($nome && $titulo) {
    echo htmlentities(colidirTituloComNome($titulo, $nome));
}
```

Comment: Acho que _responder_ por _responder_ não adianta. Sua resposta é enorme para algo "simples" (se é que seja possível fazer o que o dono da pergunta quer). E mesmo assim, sua resposta deixa várias incógnitas quanto ao sucesso do que se pretende. Acho inválido responder gambiarra (com todo o respeito) para resolver _parcialmente_ o que se pretende. Acho que deveria postar a resposta que atenda a questão, ou então não responder nada.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível de modo fácil, nativo ou automatizado pois para criar esse tipo de algorítimo você precisa definir padrões para que o código siga. E como se trata de nome próprio, a quantidade de padrões possíveis são impraticáveis de se prever e analisar.

Comment: Concordo. Não é possível fazer o que se pretende sem uma referência.