# Pegar nome do site pelo link

Tags: php, link

```html
//  IRIA PUXAR DO BANCO DE DADOS OS LINKS, MAS ASSIM JÁ DA UM EXEMPLO DE COMO IRIA FICAR.

$listalinks = "http://site1.com/embed1/CODIGO http://site2.com/embed2/CODIGO http://site3.com/embed3/CODIGO http://site4.com/embed4/CODIGO"; 

function pegaListadeUrlDaBase() {
 

   // Exemplo com links em uma única string da base, separados por ' ';
   $links_text = "$listalinks";
   return explode(" ", $links_text);
}

$urls = pegaListadeUrlDaBase();


foreach($urls as $url) {
   $nome = explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))[0];
   echo "<a href='$url'>$nome</a>";
}
```

coloco assim e não pega.

Comment: qual é a ideia, o que você esta precisando, eu não compreendi a sua pergunta.

Comment: Não deu para entender nada

Comment: como assim *"cadastrar esses links no servidor"*?

Comment: queria cadastrar no banco de dados a primeira partea ali, e com php retornasse a segunda parte ali, mas só pegando as primeiras partes da url que é site1,site2,site3,site4, sem o .com, e formatando deixando do jeito que postei ali na segunda parte criando um link com a primeira parte da url do site

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar o nome do site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231279/como-pegar-o-nome-do-site)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função nativa do php `parse_url` para recuperar as informações de uma URL. Dessa forma:

```
$listalinks = "http://site1.com/embed1/CODIGO http://site2.com/embed2/CODIGO http://site3.com/embed3/CODIGO http://site4.com/embed4/CODIGO";

$urls = explode(" ", $listalinks);


foreach($urls as $url) {
   $nome = explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))[0];
   echo "<a href='$url'>$nome</a>";
}
```

Este exemplo irá printar:

```
<a href='http://site1.com/embed1/CODIGO'>site1</a>
<a href='http://site2.com/embed2/CODIGO'>site2</a>
<a href='http://site3.com/embed3/CODIGO'>site3</a>
<a href='http://site4.com/embed4/CODIGO'>site4</a>
```

Veja a documentação:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Comment: Queria cadastrar no banco de dados toda a parte de cima, e mostrar com php a segunda parte, mas pegando somente a primeira parte dos links que seria o site1,site,2,site,3,site4 sem o .com, deixando da forma que tá na segunda parte ali, sabe uma solução?

Comment: Amigo.. você vai simplesmente retornar a lista de URL's da base e aplicar o código.. Atualizei a resposta para mostrar o resultado exatamente como você solicitou com o <a href...

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu queria, mas no caso as url ficam todas salvas juntas, no exemplo ai ali no return, estão separadas, como eu iria conseguir fazer dessa forma? Não entendo muito bem de php

Comment: se você der um exemplo de como fica salvo realmente eu posso te dar uma solução amigo.

Comment: Eu tenho uma areá que cadastra os links, e tem um textarea chamado LINKS, mas em vez de eu cadastrar um link por vez, eu coloco todos links de uma vez 
http://site1.com/embed1/CODIGO
http://site2.com/embed2/CODIGO
http://site3.com/embed3/CODIGO
http://site4.com/embed4/CODIGO

no seu exemplo, funciona, mas não se os links tiver tudo em uma tabela só, como ficaria essa parte return para este caso?

Comment: amigo.. se os links ficam em uma única string separados por um espaço. você pode dar um `explode(" ", $string_de_urls)` antes para retornar um array com os links separados.

Comment: Editei a resposta para um exemplo onde os links estão em uma única string. Caso não funcionar, você poderia atualizar sua pergunta com o formato exatamente como está na sua base de dados para que eu possa usar.

Comment: pode me ajudar mais uma vez? estou tentando puxar a string $listalinks, colocando ali  dentro do $links_text ="$listalinks"; e não está puxando nada, sabe o que é? se eu coloco em qualquer outra parte do site, está aparecendo, mas ali parece que não

Comment: $listalinks é onde armazena os links

Comment: Atualiza sua pergunta com o código, senão fica complicado de eu ajudar sem ver.

Comment: Atualizado, tem como dar uma força?

Comment: blz amigo.. o método que eu criei ali foi um exemplo de como seria buscando da base e retornando a lista.. mas já que você tem esses valores salvos.. você pode simplesmente remover o método. e fazer `$urls = explode(" ", $listalinks);`

Comment: Pegou 100%, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Creio que isto servirá para você:

**index.php**

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="envia.php">
   Links: <label for="nome"></label>
          <textarea name="nome" id="nome" cols="20" rows="8"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" />
</form>

<?php
include("conexao.php");

$sql = "SELECT seu_campo FROM sua_tabela";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  echo "<a href=".$linha['nome'].">".$linha['nome']."</a><br>";
}
?>
```

No `index.php`, você insere os valores no textarea e depois eles são mostrados como link logo abaixo, depois da inserção.

**envia.php**

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");

$nomes = $_POST['nome'];
$separar = explode("\n", $nomes);

foreach($separar as $nome){
    $query = "INSERT INTO sua_tabela (seu_campo) VALUES ('".$nome."')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}

echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!";

?>
```

Aqui é onde faz toda a magia de separar por quebra de linha usando o `explode` e então consegue inserir no banco de dados.

**conexao.php**

```
<?php
  $servidor = "localhost";
  $usuario = "root";
  $senha = "1234";
  $dbname = "teste";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

?>
```

E este é o arquivo conexão que usei, apenas troque o valor das variáveis pelos seus dados do mysql.

Por fim, Substitua onde diz *"sua_tabela"* e *"seu_campo"* pelos seus e creio que funcionará tranquilo.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ssite=('http://site.com'); 

$q=@file_get_contents($ssite); 

preg_match_all('#<title>([^<\/]{1,})<\/title>#i',$q,$match);

$otitle=($match[1][0]); 

echo $otitle; // Mostra frase do title
```